# How get property mixin class?

Tags: extjs

My example :

```
Ext.define('A', {type:'car',speed:1000});
Ext.define('B', {type:'bus',people:10});
Ext.define('Person', {
    config: {
            name: 'Eugene',
            surname : 'Popov'
    },
      mixins:{
          car:'A',
          bus:'B'
      }
  });




var obj= Ext.create('Person');

console.log(obj.type);//car
console.log(obj.speed);//1000
console.log(obj.people);//10
```

And I want get property from B class ?

`console.log(obj.........type);`// I want get bus !  \

It is possible ?

Comment: obj.mixins.bus.type ?

Comment: do you need mixins? It's not really clear what you want to achieve.. I  would guess it's more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/G2x2a/ Mixins are more to add extra 'inherited' methods or properties to an existing class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

console.log(obj.mixins.bus.type);
http://www.sencha.com/learn/sencha-class-system

Best regards